# Confusing periodic boundary condition with `PeriodicInterpolation`

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, implementation-details

When using `NDSolve` to solve a PDE with a periodic boundary condition, for example,
$y(0,t)=y(L,t)$ using `"DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral"` but without `PeriodicInterpolation->True`. After I obtained the solution, I plotted the grid and found that the grid used was uniform.

But according to the [Mathematica tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1106740037):
*The pseudospectral derivative approximation is only applicable when the grid points are spaced corresponding to the Chebyshev–Gauss–Lobatto points or when the grid is uniform with `PeriodicInterpolation->True`,*

This means that if one uses `DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral` but doesn't add `PeriodicInterpolation->True` the grid should have consisted of the Chebyshev–Gauss–Lobatto points, that is, it should be **nonuniform**. Nevertheless, based on the fact that the grid used in the abovementioned computation was uniform by only using a periodic boundary condition but **never** applying `PeriodicInterpolation->True`, could we say that a periodic boundary condition implies `PeriodicInterpolation->True`.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This means that if one uses `"DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral"` but doesn't add `PeriodicInterpolation->True`…

But how will you add `PeriodicInterpolation -> True`?

Please notice `PeriodicInterpolation` is not an option for `NDSolve` and AFAIK there's no way to adjust it inside `NDSolve`. It's an option of `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``, which is called internally by `NDSolve` when solving PDE with `TensorProductGrid` method. If one adds periodic b.c. to `NDSolve`, `NDSolve` will identify it and interprete it as setting `PeriodicInterpolation -> True` in `` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``. This can be verified with `TraceInternal -> True`:

```
eqn = With[{u = u[t, x]}, D[u, t] == D[u, x, x]];
ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-10 (x - 1)^2];
bc = u[t, 0] == u[t, 2];

Trace[NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25, 
        "MinPoints" -> 25, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}], 
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[__], TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union
(*
{HoldForm@
  NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[{2}, {{0., 0.0833333, 0.166667, 0.25, 0.333333, 
   0.416667, 0.5, 0.583333, 0.666667, 0.75, 0.833333, 0.916667, 1., 1.08333, 1.16667, 
   1.25, 1.33333, 1.41667, 1.5, 1.58333, 1.66667, 1.75, 1.83333, 1.91667, 2.}}, 
 DifferenceOrder -> {"Pseudospectral"}, PeriodicInterpolation -> {True}]}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice illustration @xzczd!! So the conclusion is: a periodic boundary condition in the `NDSlove` implies `PeriodicInterpolation->True`.

Comment: @jsxs To be precise, when `"TensorProductGrid"` is chosen. If the new-added "FiniteElement" method is chosen, the interpretation is probably different, but I haven't explore it because I'm still in _v9_. (Update: a quick test shows the interpretation seems to be a `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[…]` when `"FiniteElement"` is chosen for `"SpatialDiscretization"`)